# insert div between content using foreach with simple html dom parser

Tags: php, html, simpledom

I'm using PHP simple dom parser, says my markup is like this

```
<table class="tb">..</table>
<table>..</table>
<table>..</table>
```

I tried

```
$banner = '<div class="ads">blablabla</div>';
foreach($html->find('tb') as $table){
    $table->outertext .= $banner;
}
```

but it loops all the table. I tried `find('div[class="tb"][1]')` but it doesn't work. I want a div appear only once btw the first and second table.

Comment: you want to use oly php no need of Jquery ?

Comment: @HariniSekar just php

Comment: @kevinabelita why need to put inside? I put outside and it worked, just that it loop through all the table, I only want the banner to be appear once btw the first and second table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are trying to find div with class *tb* whereas you should be looking for the table element. Next, to 'append' the existing text with the `$banner` value, you need to use `.=` operator so that your table code is not erased. And then finally, you save the changes. The code should look like:

```
foreach($html->find('table[class=tb]') as $element){
       echo $element->src . '<br>';
       $element->outertext .= $banner;
}

$html->save();
```

The output would be:

```
<table class="tb">..</table><div class="ads">banner</div>  <table>..</table>  <table>..</table>
```

Comment: what happen if I don't save the it? because in the end I echo $html

Comment: @user3522725 As per [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm), looks like save() is used when you want to save the contents into a file, for your case, you can go ahead without it.

Comment: says I've 5 table, I used ur code, it has 5 banner within them.. that's the problem

Comment: @user3522725 Could you [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) the structure of those 5 table?